# Any recommendations for a PDF 3D SDK with C++ interface

Tags: c++, pdf, sdk, 3d

I'm on the look out for a Cor C++ library / SDK that will allow me to either write a 3d PDF directly, or convert a DXF or DWG into a 3D PDF.  So far I have come up with the [PDF3d library](http://www.pdf3d.co.uk/) which fits the bill, but is reasonably costly and has an expensive per user run time license.  I don't mind a reasonable SDK cost, but the per seat cost kills it for me.

Anyone aware of any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use PDF XChange a lot for 2D CAD plots to PDF and it works well. I don't know if (I don't think so) it does 3D. I could find no mention of it at first glance on their site.

Your other option is a 3D DWF. Also consider that DWG TrueView is a free viewer and printer that handles 3D DWGs natively. You used to be able to automate TrueView through COM but I'm not sure if that is still so. Here is a blog post on some automation of Trueview - http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2007/10/au-handouts-t-1.html

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about TrueView.  I only use AutoCAD for viewing / testing translators so this is a real bonus.

Answer (score 2):

I know that acrobat itself provides their free SDK 8.1 which supports 3d features as given in http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acrobat_SDK_whats_new.pdf
But I am not sure how much work is required to plugin for conversions.
Hope this might work for you.

Comment: While free, the acrobat SDK requires the user to have acrobat installed on their PC, which equates to a per user runtime cost.  The Adobe PDF library with 3d is a possible alternative, though I haven't checked out prices as yet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a per seat cost for Adobe PDF library

Answer (score 2):

SimLab SDK can convert DWG/DXF to PDF 3D. It's not free, but the price is reasonable and per-seat fee is small: http://www.simlab-soft.com/SDK.aspx

Another option is HOOPS Publish from TechSoft3D. Could be pricy: http://www.techsoft3d.com/our-products/hoops-publish